# Python classes that contain themselves?

Tags: python

I am implementing an algorithm, and I require a class I have called 'Node' to contain a list of other Nodes.  How is this done in Python?  It seems like a very common thing to do, but I haven't been able to turn up results on it.

```
class Node():
  def __init__(self, n):
    self.myFriend = n
    return
```

This is the essence of what I want to do.  But of course, it isn't possible to initialize the class without having an instance of it already initialized...

Comment: Why not add it after initialization ?

Answer (score 3):

```
class Node():
    def __init__(self, n = None):
        self.my_friend = n

a = Node()
b = Node(a)
c = Node(b)
a.my_friend = c
```

results in three Nodes in a ring.

Comment: You could even do `a = Node(); a.my_friend = a` which would mean you are your own friend.

Comment: For some reason it seemed to me like there should be a better way to do this, but after asking the question I guess it's pretty much the only option.  Thanks